# Is there a any way to send values from Unity project to another program?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

how can i send data from program which is made with Unity 3D to another program which is made with c# (.NET Framework) in real-time ? Thanks.

Comment: Assuming your Unity program is c# i'd recommend looking into using Windows Coummunication Foundation since that is a suitably high-level approach than using sockets - see https://gorillacoding.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/using-wcf-for-inter-process-communication/

Comment: i know at least 10 ways of communicate between 2 program... so your another program is in another machine or same machine?  and the oher program in c# uses sockets or other way of dialog?

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't specific and i'm not familiar with unity and c# but you should look into sockets. Normally in any language, you use sockets to communicate with other platforms.

From a high level, you have a server and then clients can connect to that server and you can have a bidirectional communication flow where the client can send message to the server and the server can receive those messages and send stuff back or do an action. Here's a YouTube video of c# sockets -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xgLRe7QV6QI